# I find no solution to this type conflict. Where did i go wrong?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, abbyy, finereader

I've been trying to fix the following mistake for a few hours.
I got the ABBYY FineReader SDK to work with the OCR-API. So far so good to get familiar with the SDK, I tried to get it running with an ABBYY sample. But the error (shown below) stopped me in doing so. I have absolutely no idea what could cause this error. I first thought about some name equalities but I was wrong.
I am looking forward to any help.

The error output is : "TypeError: Typenkonflikt (type conflict)
Code:

```
function ProcessImage(){
    var imagePath = location.pathname+"foto.jpg";
    var docu = FREngine.CreateFRDocument();
    console.log(docu);
 
try {
        // Add image file to document
        DisplayMessage( "Loading image..." );
        docu.AddImageFile(imagePath); //ERROR Typeconflict
```

Comment: code goes into the question, not in comments, please [edit] the question to add relevant code and information

Comment: Yes and please format your code so it's easier to read - it'll help people solve the problem :)

Comment: Sorry, i had problems with formatting..

Comment: This has something to do with your Javascript framework, which apparently messes up with types. I would suggest changing the framework. The better option is to quit JavaScript and use language with strict types, such as Java.